# WSO2 API Manager https://localhost:9443/admin-dashboard is not accesible

Tags: wso2

I have downloaded WSO2 API Manager, configured according to the steps provided in document.

Although I am able to access https://localhost:9446/carbon/admin/login.jsp and publisher, portal.

I am not able to access admin-dashboard.
Response is:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.

Steps tried:

Added following in `carbon.xml`:

```
EnableHTTPAdminConsole true EnableHTTPAdminConsole
```

Can anyone figure out what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is changed since 2.0.0.

```
https://localhost:9446/admin
```

Comment: I am following this link
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+REST+Client 
and want to configure Analytics in Settings as shown.

I am able to login to admin as you mentioned , but do there is no option to configre analytics as mentioned above.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I am using  2.1.0.